# Got Schengen visa from Spain - no longer traveling to Spain but now traveling to France...will it be an issue?

Tags: schengen, spain, schengen-visas

I had initial plans to travel to Spain and got my visa, but due to my partner's work schedule had to cancel the plan to Spain and am now planning to go to France. Will it be an issue if I do not go to Spain and straightaway go to France with the visa issued by Spain?

Not sure of the practice. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to at least enter through Spain. And then, maybe take a train or a budget airline into your destination in France. Even though the change in your itinerary is genuine and not pre-planned, you never know if you'll be able to convince the immigration officer in France.

Comment: And if you're from a country that isn't easily favoured by the Schengen visa regime, you may be flagged as an abuser of visa regulations.